# Is there a way to take a list of different files and group them together in a separate list based off identical characters on R?

Tags: r, list

Is there a way to take a list of different files and group them together in a separate list based off identical characters on R?

So taking a list like:

```
list_of_files <- c("file1.tif", "file1.png", "file1.rds", "file2.tif", "file2.png")
```

And then ending up with a new variable that when called returns something like:

```
new_variable[1]
>>> "file1.tif" "file1.png" "file1.rds"

new_variable[2]
>>> "file2.tif" "file2.png"
```

Once again, I want to be able to group all of the files by identical characters in a particular spot. The one I am using is obviously not just called file1 and file2, but for simplicity's sake, those are the file names I created. And it is also more than just 2 different files so a simple if statement probably will not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` based on the files without extension into a `list`

```
out <- split(list_of_files, tools::file_path_sans_ext(list_of_files))
out
$file1
[1] "file1.tif" "file1.png" "file1.rds"

$file2
[1] "file2.tif" "file2.png"
```

and extract the `list` elements with `$` or `[[`

```
out$file1
out[[1]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it where I don't have to type out file1 or file2 and have it automatically do it itself? There are A LOT of different files on the one I'm working on, that's why

Comment: @NathanDrake The code `split` is doing this automaticaly and storing it in a `list`.  I showed the way to extract from `list`.  You don't need to extract the list elements as you can loop over the `list` with `lapply` etc.

Comment: How would I do it using lapply? I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @NathanDrake what is the end goal here.  The `split` does exactly what you asked in the question i.e. group them together in a `list`

Comment: To take all of these files and to make a <div> with them that includes links for each file to be downloaded in its appropriate div. So, the files I am working with are all date exclusive. The ones that are within a particular date, I want to group together (the file names have the dates present) so that when the div prints out, it shows all of the files for that particular date and shows links to them. I have currently made a function that does just that and all I need right now is a way to make a div appear for each date... if that makes sense.

Comment: @NathanDrake that info was not in the asked question.  Sorry, I am not sure how much extended this question would be.   I answered the one you asked in the current post

Comment: I'm aware! I am trying to do it one step at a time starting with grouping all of the files by identical characters within a certain range. How would lapply work?

Comment: `out` is a `list` of grouped filenames.  you loop over the `list` with `lapply` `lapply(out, f1)` and `f1` is your function.  I am not sure how many files, your function takes as input.  So, you may have to ask another question about it. thanks

Comment: My function takes two inputs: one being the files and the other being the date! When I try doing lapply, it gives me back an error that "date" is missing.

Comment: @NathanDrake ok.  Have a great day!

Comment: @NathanDrake thank you for accepting.   Your comment about function taking two inputs.  I couldn't understand really from the comments what your follow ups are.  That is the reason I didn't spent time on it.